# indings: python bindings disabled due to the following missing dependencies: cppyy

Tags: networking, ns-3, python-bindings

[I want to install PyViz visualizer in ns3.37 but I am getting this error in MacOS Ventura version 13.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmylw.png)

[EXPECTED OUTPUT SHOULD BE :
PyViz visualizer              : ON
Python Bindings               : ON
BECAUSE PyViz is dependent on Python Bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMgvs.png)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
./ns3 configure
```

it will show the installed & missing files (in different color). Install those dependencies. Hope this will work.

If not, try to enable python bindings by running the following command.

```
./ns3 configure --enable-python-bindings
```

Comment: This worked for me using ```ns3``` to build. What of ```waf``` builds? It seems to not work